capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
I'm trying to make an app with angular Ionic + capacitor. One of the components must be able to read NFC messages.
if i try ionic serve on visual studio code, it works just fine. but, when i try 'run app' on Android Studio i got 9 errors:
Build anrdoid: failed At 25/07/2024 12:54 with 9 errors, 2 warnings
warning: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.  

Errors:
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\Seminario-UTN\Frontend\SUBD-transport\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\com\chariotsolutions\nfc\plugin\NfcPlugin.java:550: error: cannot find symbol
                        nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(p2pMessage, getActivity());
                                  ^
  symbol:   method setNdefPushMessage(NdefMessage,Activity)
  location: variable nfcAdapter of type NfcAdapter

plus 8 more just like that one and
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\Seminario-UTN\Frontend\SUBD-transport\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\cordova\plugins\Diagnostic.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
9 errors
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Since I am a student and I have no previous experience working with Ionic and my experience with Angular is very limited, I will try to comment step by step on what I did.
Searching the internet I found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@awesome-cordova-plugins/nfc
so I did the following:
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/core
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/nfc
npm install @ionic-native/core
npm install @ionic-native/nfc
npm install phonegap-nfc

app.module.ts:
import { NFC } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/nfc/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true },
    NFC
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

and in NfcReaderComponent:
import { NFC } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/nfc/ngx';
...
constructor(
 private nfc: NFC, <--
 private ticketService: TicketService,
 private transportService: TransportService,
 private router: Router
 ) { }
...

ionic cap add android
ionic build
npx cap sync
ionic cap open android

here on android studio is where i got the problems with capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
i try removing and re instaling both node_modules and android.
package.json:
{
  "name": "SUBD-transport",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.8.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/nfc": "^6.8.0",
    "@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^6.1.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "6.1.0",
    "@capacitor/geolocation": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "6.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.5",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/nfc": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^8.0.0",
    "@zxing/library": "^0.21.2",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^17.0.1",
    "compress-json": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^7.1.4",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "phonegap-nfc": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^18.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "6.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/pako": "^2.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^48.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}

capacitor.config.ts:
import type { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.subd.transport',
  appName: 'SUBD-transport',
  webDir: 'www'
};

export default config;

variables.gradle:
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.8.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.6.1'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.12.0'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.6.2'
    coreSplashScreenVersion = '1.0.1'
    androidxWebkitVersion = '1.9.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.5'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.5.1'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'
}

npx cap sync
√ Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 7.20s
√ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 2.77ms
[info] Found 2 Cordova plugins for android:
       cordova.plugins.diagnostic@7.1.4    
       phonegap-nfc@1.2.0
√ copy android in 7.40s
√ Updating Android plugins in 24.40ms
[info] Found 7 Capacitor plugins for android:
       @capacitor-community/barcode-scanner@4.0.1
       @capacitor/app@6.0.0
       @capacitor/geolocation@6.0.0
       @capacitor/haptics@6.0.0
       @capacitor/keyboard@6.0.1
       @capacitor/status-bar@6.0.0
       @capacitor/storage@1.2.5
- update android [info] Found 2 Cordova plugins for android:
       cordova.plugins.diagnostic@7.1.4
       phonegap-nfc@1.2.0
√ update android in 335.93ms
√ copy web in 47.57ms
√ update web in 52.12ms
[info] Sync finished in 8.077s


update your java version.

@NajamUsSaqib i tried with java 8, 11, 17 and 22 always same error.
if i manually change in variables.gradle { compileSdkVersion = 34 to 28 } then the error disappears, but, then a new one shows up:
In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

It seems like I solved it by going to:
File > Project Structure > Modules: capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
in Android Studio and setting:
Compile Sdk Version: 28
Source Compatibility: $JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
Targen Compatibility: $JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
image for reference
